# Capturing application screen with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, screen-capture, webpage-screenshot

Is it possible to capture the entire window as screenshot using JavaScript?
The application might contain many iframes and div's where content are loaded asynchronously.

I have explored canvas2image but it works on an html element, using the same discards any iframe present on the page.

I am looking for a solution where the capture will take care of all the iframes present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, widh Puppeteer it is possible.

1 - Just install the dependency:

```
npm i puppeteer-core
```

2 - Create JavaScript file, screenshot.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto('https://yourweb.com');
   await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});

   await browser.close();
})();
```

3 - Run:

```
node screenshot.js
```

[Source](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP want exactly. But canvas2image is a client side library and capture what the client sees. This one is a server side script and capture the static page without dynamic contents. For example, it doesn't contain logged in user details, their data, etc.

Comment: With puppeteer you can do everything you do in Chromium. It has very few limitations, and if you want to, you can login before on the page in question. I can help you if you want.

Comment: You can also use it from client sides, using https://github.com/browserify/browserify

Comment: @Edd does it work when you have frameset and iframes on the page. In my case there can be nested iframes as well.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to capture the contents of an iframe using ONLY JavaScript in the webpage (No extensions, or application running outside the browser on a users system) is to use the [`HTMLIFrameElement.getScreenshot()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/getScreenshot) API in Firefox. This API is non-standard, and ONLY works in Firefox.

[image: Browser compatibility chart]

For any other browser, no. An iframe is typically sandboxed, and as such it is not accessible by the browser [by design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

The best way to get a screenshot of a webpage that I have found and use, is an instance of [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) or [Headless Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode). These will take a screenshot of everything on the page, just as a user would see it.

Comment: The edit doesn't looks good. If the OP want to add this as a service in their web application, headless chrome/firefox isn't a choice. Because OP doesn't have access to the system

Comment: You can easily use headless chrome/firefox in a web application. (I use it in several, which is why I added it as an option) While it may be more involved, you can create an API where you pass a url, and get back image data. You can then use AJAX to communicate with this API in a web application. https://c.flm.pw/2018-08/kannD9.png

Comment: Can you open headless chrome on a remote system with javascript?

Comment: @SagarV You would use some form of AJAX to use/open headless chrome on a server you control.

Comment: Not on server. on client side. for example, in google, when you click feedback button, they'll attach a screenshot. Like that

Comment: If the webpage you are trying to capture has iframes with a source of a different domain then the webpage, this is NOT possible. If your webpage has no iframes, or the iframes are from the SAME domain as the webpage, you can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are not the best things to be "screenshoted", because of their nature; they can include async elements, frames or something like that, they are usually responsive etc...

For your purpose the best way is to use external api or an external service, I think is not a good idea to try doing that with JS.

You should try https://www.url2png.com/

Comment: I think OP want to add it in their website not for their personal use. Don't recommend a tool when they ask for a method to do something.

Comment: exactly, I want to capture screenshot based on events